# How i can to remove "\n" in data return from cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get an image from website with NodeJS and Cheerio. The image URL returned has `\n` in front of it. How can I remove the `\n`?

This is the code:

```
$("div[class=xxxx] img").attr("src")
```

But Cheerio returns `\nhttp://www.xxxxx.com/example.jpg`

I tried to use:

```
var image = $("div[class=xxxx] img").attr("src").replace(\n,"")
var image = $("div[class=xxxx] img").attr("src").toString().replace(\n,"")
```

But it does not work.

Comment: The newline character in  `.replace(\n,"")` should be in quotes; `.replace("\n","")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is a newline. You can remove it using the [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

Try the following:

```
$("div[class=xxxx] img").attr("src").trim();
```

Comment: thank you for answer . i tried it not wok  "Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined"

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof $("div[class=xxxx] img").attr("src"));` output?

Comment: thank you for answer. I solved the problem. have some value is undefined

Comment: This will not remove \n symbols in the middle of string

Comment: @rendom, no it won't. Check out Bishoy Hanna's answer below if you want to remove all newlines in a string.

Answer (score 2):

The below is the only which worked for me

```
.replace(/\n/g,'')
```